# Weighting Dyads

Tags: weighted-data, dyadic-data

I am currently working on a project on the causes of war. The data set I use includes cases of both civil and international wars. I intend to include both types of war in the analysis, but I believe doing so will spoil the results, unless I weight the data appropriately.

The reason is: civil war, by definition, starts and ends within a single country. In contrast, international war involves at least two countries. Since the data set is on a country-year basis, I will have to include two countries in the analysis for one international war.

How can I solve this problem? Can I simply create a weighting variable that assigns the value 1 to the country-years that correspond to a civil war, and 0.5 those that correspond to international war?

Or is it more complicated than that?